# Google services don't work on apps but work on browser after changing SIM card

Tags: internet, sim-card, google-apps

I changed the SIM card in my cell phone and Google apps such as Google Maps, YouTube, etc. no longer works, saying I was offline. Yet they still work if accessed from a web browser.

How to get the Google apps work instead of accessing from the browser?

Comment: If the new sim card belongs to a different mobile network provider you need to apply the new settings. Usually you are getting those settings via a special SMS. Some times the SMS may got lost or arrives with several hours delay. Try to reboot the device and remove + reinsert the sim card.